how to set a image normalization similar to the default scale for SAOImageDS9 zscale

I want to draw this picture using mmatplotlib, and I want to set the normalization to be Exactly Same as zscale (as in the below image)
for example, I can use simple_norm or general ImageNormalize
but I do not know how to set the parameters

I'm reasonably certain that the only parameters that you need to set are vmin and vmax in simple_norm. From the look of your colorbar vmin should be about 8.25 and vmax should be about 10.6.
